# Software - Synergy between laptop and desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, synergy

I am working at a university, and have been given a wired-desktop; it doesn't have a wireless card on it, or another wired port - and I also have a laptop that connects to the university's wireless network.

I want to use [synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) between my laptop and desktop, but I think that my laptop's wifi connection is a different subnet than the wired connection the desktop has. I've tried changing the ip-address that synergy tries to connect to to the server's forward facing IP, and the domain.name.IP, but none of that seemed to work.

My laptop's got an open wired port, but the desktop doesn't.

Is there something I'm missing in putting in the correct IP address for the two machines to connect with the proper domain listed (like remote-desktop connection?).

Thanks for taking the time to read this - also synergy rocks and we should all give them money c:

~~
On my ipconfig I see that my laptop's DNS Suffix is utdallas.edu and the desktop is campus.ad.utdallas.edu - so I'm thinking they're completely separate.

Comment: you should post the wifi connection info and the desktops. But to be honest your university probably has the wifi completely segregated from the lan. You should talk to the network admin at your university.

Comment: Yeah I'll email the network admin - see what's what.

Comment: Please keep in mind that, by default, Synergy is unencrypted.

Comment: Yeah, synergy prompted me about that to add a password to it; so I always enable encryption.